# PrimeNG paginator can render templates?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular 4 and primeNG library.

I have this template

```
<div class="owned-container-body" *ngFor="let product of ownedProducts">
    <div class="owned-items">
      <div class="product-name">{{product.description}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="owned-items">
      <app-subscribe-button [product]="product">

      </app-subscribe-button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and sometimes this become really huge, so i want to use pagination,
ownedProduct is an array of objects. So i am wondering how can i show this template on a paginator page with a chunk of data.
Can it be somthinglike this

```
<p-paginator rows="10" totalRecords="owned.products.length">

<div class="owned-container-body" *ngFor="let product of ownedProductsChunk">
    <div class="owned-items">
      <div class="product-name">{{product.description}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="owned-items">
      <app-subscribe-button [product]="product">

      </app-subscribe-button>
    </div>
  </div>

</p-paginator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not surround your main `div` with `p-paginator`. You communicate betwwen this `div` and `p-paginator` through `onPageChange` event.

So your HTML code should be something like :

```
<p-paginator rows="10" [totalRecords]="ownedProducts.length" (onPageChange)="paginate($event)"></p-paginator>

<div class="owned-container-body" *ngFor="let product of ownedProductsChunk">
  <div class="owned-items">
    <div class="product-name">{{product.description}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="owned-items">
    {{product.id}} : {{product.name}}
  </div><br/>
</div>
```

Then, you just have to slice your `ownedProducts` to fill your `ownedProductsChunk` array :

```
paginate(event) {
     this.ownedProductsChunk = this.ownedProducts.slice(event.first, event.first+event.rows);
  }
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pteRlUuNkIQ8SZ5yedCl?p=preview)

Comment: I think you are right I made same conclusion after some time, I'll mark it as an answer after implementing